# Primitive Data Types - BYTE in Java

Tags: java

Can you help me explain more detail about this sentence:

"BYTE: They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation."
Source:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Thank you!

Comment: Which part you didn't understand?

Comment: it means BYTE type can be used as int but with smaller limits: -2^7 to 2^7 -1

Comment: I think you can ignore it. In my 17 years as a Java programmer I have never seen type `byte` (nor `short`) used only for documenting a limited range. On one hand I agree that it could be done, on the other hand, when no one else does it, I doubt that it will help if you try it.

Comment: "a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation." This sentence is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

A byte will store -128 to +127.  This could help form some documentation, for example it could be used to store a percentage, e.g.

`byte pcentComplete = 99;`

However, naming the variable is far more important than deliberately limiting it.

Answer (score 0):

For that reason:

> The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

If you want to store 128 you will need an int but if you are working with numbers between this range (-128,127) it could be recommended byte instead of int and you will know that the maximum number it will be 127.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am not understand this key word: "help to clarify your code" and "serve as a form of documentation." Can you help me!

Answer (score 0):

A byte is generally uses when there is a large array or stream of 8-bit bytes. If there is only one value, I just use an `int` or a `long`.  A byte might indicate a small number, but code which checks a valid range is better.

```
public void setPercent(int percent) {
    if (percent < 0 || percent > 100)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid percent: " + percent);
```

I find a `byte` is only meaningful as a description of range is the valid value is exactly -128 to 127 or 8-bit. (Unsigned byte would be more appropriate really)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am not understand this key word: "help to clarify your code" and "serve as a form of documentation." Can you help me!

Comment: @ĐạiHoàngKim when you make a variable a `byte` you make it clear the value must be between -128 and 127 as this is the range of values it can have.